# Bad breaking line in paragraph

Tags: html, css

I have some block of text, and I put it between the `<p>` tag. My problem is that the line is breaking badly (the word is cut in the middle). Check the screenhost:

[Screen of bad breaking the word promoted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apIwm.png)

I want that word (promoted) on the new line. My code is:

```
  <p>Share your server on social platforms to promote it.</p>
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: We need to see some code. But this looks like `word-break: break-all`.

Comment: I would suggest that you change the tags to HTML, CSS, instead of PHP, as this has very little to do with PHP, and more about markup and style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a HTML/CSS problem, nothing to do with PHP. You can use `word-break: break-word`.

If above solution doesn't work for your case, some code snippet will help to debug it better.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a CSS class to the paragraph will break the word as you want it. Simply add a class, or make an inline CSS style of `overflow-wrap: break-word;`

```css
p {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
 <p>Share your server on social platforms to promote it.</p>
```

Comment: `overflow-wrap: break-word` is exactly what he does not want. It is already breaking within the word itself, which is unwanted behaviour in this case.

Comment: Isn't the problem that the word promote is broken up into two words? Wouldn't `overflow-wrap: break-word` fix that?

Comment: This behaviour looks like `word-break: break-all`, if you add `overflow-wrap: break-word`, the problem will still be there (https://jsfiddle.net/6wngoorr/). On top of that, just like `break-word` already sounds like, it would also break within words in some scenarios.